# How can I know if a provisioning profile is app-store or ad-hoc using only the shell?

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

Given a provisioning profile. What commands will tell me if it is an app-store or an ad-hoc profile (or neither of those two types)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ad hoc profile will contain a XML section that lists the devices.  That doesn't exist for App Store or enterprise.

So...

```
pmills$ strings /Users/pmills/X_Ad_Hoc.mobileprovision  | grep ProvisionedDevices
```

...displays:

```
<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
```

...while...

```
pmills$ strings /Users/pmills/X_App_Store.mobileprovision  | grep ProvisionedDevices
```

...displays nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Another method would be to use plistbudy to parse the mobileprovision file and look for the `ProvisionsAllDevices` value:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Print :ProvisionsAllDevices' /dev/stdin <<< $(security cms -D -i <path_to_profile.mobileprovision> )
```

if the command returns true (with return code 0), it is either an app store profile, or and In House distribution profile.  If the command cannot find the plist entry (command will return a 1), it is a developer profile.

Comment: Note that `ProvisionsAllDevices` is the correct key to look for if you want to see if it is an In House or App Store profile.  Conversely, you could look for `ProvisionedDevices` key to see if it is an Ad Hoc profile.  I tried to look at the differences between an In House (Enterprise) profile and the App Store profile, and other than the certificate, I couldn't see a difference in the keys between the two.

Comment: Oh! I see. I didn't realize you were referring to "Enterprise" when you wrote "In House". That's handy then. I'd upvote you if I had the reputation.

Comment: No problem.  The other answer will work the same way.  If the mobileprovision file lists individual devices, it is a development profile.  If not, it could either be an App Store profile or a In House Distribution (Enterprise) profile.